# android.support.v4.view.ViewPager does not disallow child scrolling in android 2.2?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i have my app with android support v4 using ViewPager, one of my views has a HorizontalScrollView inside a page, in 4.0 up it can scroll normally but running 2.2 the ViewPager is moving onto next.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you can try this:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
    if(v instanceof HorizontalScrollView){
        return true;
    }
    return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
}

}
```

**Explanation:**

This will tell the viewpager that if the view in the one you scrolled is a horizontal list view, then he needs to ignore the scroll and leave the horizontal scroll to "handle it", BUT you need to have in mind that any scroll (horizontal scroll) outside the horizontal scroll view will make your viewpager to change page, ALSO that if you scroll from the exterior to the inside (your finger outside the tablet and coming in) the viewpager will ignore this behavior and will move the page.